# listview shows on emulator but not on actual phone

Tags: flutter, dart

as typed above i am trying to display information using  a listview but i noticed whenever i port this app to my phone via APK it just shows the background color nothing else! maybe im using expanded wrong or something i have no clue. this app works as intended on my emulator, the emulator im using is pixel 4 api 30

code home_page.dart

```
class _SummonerProfileRouteState extends State<SummonerProfileRoute> {
  List<SummonerRank> SummonerRankList = <SummonerRank>[];

  void getSummonerRankfromApi() async {
    SummonerRankApi.getSummonerRank(summonerId).then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        SummonerRankList =
            list.map((model) => SummonerRank.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
    });
  }

  String summonerName, summonerId;
  int profileIconId, summonerLevel;
  _SummonerProfileRouteState(this.summonerName, this.summonerId,
      this.profileIconId, this.summonerLevel);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSummonerRankfromApi();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: customAppBar(),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [
                bgColorFront,
                bgColorEnd,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
                    Text(
                      summonerName,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 35,
                        fontFamily: 'Spiegel',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Level ${summonerLevel.toString()}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: customColorTextBlue,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10)),
                    Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              placeholder: "images/placeholder.jpg",
                              image:
                              "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.22.1/img/profileicon/$profileIconId.png"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: [
                        GridView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                                crossAxisCount: 2),
                            itemCount: SummonerRankList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    modeChecker(
                                        SummonerRankList[index].queueType),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'Spiegel',
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "${SummonerRankList[index].tier} ${SummonerRankList[index].rank}",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: customColorTextBlue,
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "${SummonerRankList[index].leaguePoints} LP",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: customColorTextBlue,
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "${calculateWinrate(SummonerRankList[index].wins, SummonerRankList[index].losses)}% Winrate",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: customColorTextBlue,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ));
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          MyElevatedButton(
                            width: 350,
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AllChampionsListedRoute(summonerId, summonerName)));
                            },
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Spacer(),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.call_made_sharp,
                                  color: customColorTextBlue,
                                  size: 26,
                                ),
                                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5)),
                                Text(
                                  'Check champion statistics',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: customColorTextBlue,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Spacer(),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ListView` with Column widget. You cant use `Expanded` inside ListView

```dart
return Scaffold(
    appBar: customAppBar(),
    body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
          colors: [
            bgColorFront,
            bgColorEnd,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Column( //this
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
```

Comment: this does remove my ability to scroll though, i am also trying to make it responsive

Comment: you can use top level ListView  and remove inner expanded and ListView